# Insert second file contents using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to append the whole of second file contents (it is a log) in XML `<log>` tag using `awk`. I cannot combine both input files into one since I am using a `FS="\n" RS="\n\n"` which is suited for my first input file. What part should come between my `awk` code`<log>WHAT_TO_FEED_HERE?</log>`, I am unable to determine.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Input_file1:

```
Sara
123
sara@sara.com

John
456
john@john.com
```

Input_file2:

```
#This is first line along with # symbol

#There were two blank lines spaces above
#Candidatedata1 values

#Some more random text
```

I would need the final output as below:

```
<name>Sara</name>
<id>123</id>
<email>sara@sara.com</email>
<log>
#This is first line along with # symbol

#There were two blank lines spaces above
#Candidatedata1 values

#Some more random text
</log>

<name>John</name>
<id>456</id>
<email>john@john.com</email>
<log>
#This is first line along with # symbol

#There were two blank lines spaces above
#Candidatedata2 values

#Some more random text
</log>
```

I have used the below `awk` statement:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS = "\\n";RS = "\\n\\n"; print " "}
  { print "<candidate>" }
  { print "<name>"$1"</name>" }
  { print "<id>"$2"</id>" }
  { print "<email>"$3"</email>" }
  { print "<log>"WHAT_TO_FEED_HERE?"</log>" }
  { print "</candidate>" }
  {print " " }' Input_file1.txt Input_file2.txt> candidatefinaloutput.xml
```

Comment: Suggestion: pass the filename via `-v logfile="Input_file2.txt"` to awk and then read from that file via getline in the BEGIN section and store the content in a variable

Comment: I have now edited my text. Sorry for the missing items. I would need the individual logs to be present for each and every file.

Comment: No. Each of the groups will have their individual logs. I initially thought of performing a cat on the log and storing it in the file1.txt. However, not sure what delimiters to use to separate the individual elements as blank line holds good for name, id and email and log contains several blank lines.

Comment: So, `input_data.txt` and then `log_for_1.txt`, `log_for_2.txt`, `log_for_3.txt` etc.? The example output has "#Candidatedata1 " and " .. data2"

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for: input_data.txt and then log_for_1.txt, log_for_2.txt, log_for_3.txt

Comment: Ok, can't you pass `-v logfile="log_for_"`, use your own counter or FNR to `build log_for_current` by adding the number and .txt (if the log txt files follow a pattern) and then read from the current relevant file via `getline < log_for_current` and print it to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk is a bit cumbersome when you don't want to apply the same processing to all files, but it can be done.

For this use case, I'd read the content of the second file at the beginning, and use that afterwards.

```
BEGIN {
    while (getline <ARGV[2]) {
        logfile = logfile $0 "\n"
    }
    delete ARGV[2];
    FS = "\\n"; RS = "\\n\\n";
}
{
    print "<candidate>";
    print "<name>" $1 "</name>";
    print "<id>" $2 "</id>";
    print "<email>" $3 "</email>";
    print "<log>" logfile "</log>";
    print "</candidate>";
    print "";
}
```